# [C#]XML Serialize Attribut/Element must have value

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xml-attribute

I got **[XMLIgnoreAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx)**, **[VARSpecified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx#code-snippet-5)** to ignore or ignore-able value.

But is there any attribute to specified must have a value ?

I found this [Attributes That Control XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e.aspx), but nothing useful.

```
class Test
{
    [XMLIgnore]
    public string IgnoredValue;

    [XMLAttribute]
    public string AnAttribute;

    // If 'AnAttribute' length < 5 will be ignored
    public bool AnAttributeSpecified{get {return AnAttribute.Length > 5;};}

    // For this, it must have a value, is there any attribute for this?
    public string Name;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to make sure users supply a non-null, non-empty value for `Name`? If they do try to assign one of those, do you want it to throw an exception or use a default value instead?

Comment: Maybe the only way is I check the value by myself, if the value not match the rules, then throw an Exception instead. Actually ,I just want the XMLSerialize do this check.

Comment: AFAIK, the `XmlSerializer` can't do these checks for you. However, it's trivial to do them yourself by using properties for your members and validating the values in the setter.